Modifing pyinstaller executable strings
I'm trying to modify a string value in a Python executable that was compiled using PyInstaller.
I tried finding the string using hxd but i didnt find the string i wanted to change
but when I used pyinstxtractor to extract the contents of the pyinstaller executable then i got .pyc files and i managed to change the string on the .pyc file
